# Uninstall components

Tags: wix

I am building the .msi which contains 3 features.

1. feature1
2. feature2
3. feature3

While installing the product, the user has the choice to install feature1, f2, f3 or f1, f2 as per user requirement. He can install successfully.

I am facing problem while deinstalling.
My .msi file deinstalls all the installed components (ie f1,f2,f3).

Here I want to provide UI to user where he can select the component(s) which he wants to uninstall.

Can you pelase help me how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Installer doesn't support that. Uninstall means "Remove all features from the machine." It sounds like what you want is to allow the user to go into "Maintenance Mode" and turn features on and off. There are default UIs in the WiX toolset that provide that.

Ultimately, the MSI needs to stay installed so the user can uninstall everything later.